# Accessing variables out of scope in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Im trying to access this variable "scrollTween" outside of the useEffect hook. Is there way to do this?

```
  const panels = useRef([])
  const panelsContainer = useRef()

  const createPanelsRefs = (panel, index) => {
    panels.current[index] = panel
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const totalPanels = panels.current.length

    let scrollTween = gsap.to(panels.current, {
      xPercent: -100 * (totalPanels - 1),
      ease: 'none',
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: panelsContainer.current,
        pin: true,
        scrub: 1.5,
        // snap: 1 / (totalPanels - 1),
        end: () => '+=' + panelsContainer.current.offsetWidth,
      },
    })
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `useState()`. You can read the docs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate

```
const panels = useRef([])
const panelsContainer = useRef()

const createPanelsRefs = (panel, index) => {
  panels.current[index] = panel
}

const [scrollTween, setScrollTween] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
  const totalPanels = panels.current.length

  const scrollTween = gsap.to(panels.current, {
    xPercent: -100 * (totalPanels - 1),
    ease: 'none',
    scrollTrigger: {
      trigger: panelsContainer.current,
      pin: true,
      scrub: 1.5,
      // snap: 1 / (totalPanels - 1),
      end: () => '+=' + panelsContainer.current.offsetWidth,
    },
  })

  setScrollTween(scrollTween)
  }, [])
```

Comment: Hmm this cleared up the error but the animation does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: The `useEffect()`'s dependancy array is empty. So it runs only when the component mounts. You can try adding `panelsContainer.current`, `panels.current` and `totalPanels` to the dependency array to see if that helps.